# Convert a recursive function to an iteration in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, iteration

I don't manage to convert a recursive function to an iteration. 
Consider the following **function**:

```
function getTreeDataFromRows (id, rows) {
  let ret_val = []

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i]

    if (id == row.id_parent) {
      let new_element = {
        id:         row.id,
        id_parent:  row.id_parent,
        value:      row.value,
        data:       getTreeDataFromRows(row.id, rows)
      }

      for (let property in row) {
        if ('id' == property || 'id_parent' == property || 'value' == property) {
          continue
        }
        new_element[property] = row[property]
      }

      ret_val.push(new_element)
    }
  }

  return ret_val
}
```

I have as an **input** a json similar to this:

```
[{
    "id": "c-1",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-1",
    "id_parent": "c-1",
    "value": "Article 1.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-2",
    "id_parent": "c-1",
    "value": "Article 1.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "c-2",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-21",
    "id_parent": "c-2",
    "value": "Article 2.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-22",
    "id_parent": "c-2",
    "value": "Article 2.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-221",
    "id_parent": "a-22",
    "value": "Quote 221 from article 2.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-222",
    "id_parent": "a-22",
    "value": "Quote 222 from article 2.2"
  }
]
```

The **output** has to be like this:

```
[{
    "id": "c-1",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 1",
    "data": [{
        "id": "a-1",
        "id_parent": "c-1",
        "value": "Articole 1.1",
        "data": []
      },
      {
        "id": "a-2",
        "id_parent": "c-1",
        "value": "Articole 1.2",
        "data": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "c-2",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 2",
    "data": [{
        "id": "a-21",
        "id_parent": "c-2",
        "value": "Articole 2.1",
        "data": []
      },
      {
        "id": "a-22",
        "id_parent": "c-2",
        "value": "Articole 2.2",
        "data": [{
            "id": "a-221",
            "id_parent": "a-22",
            "value": "Quote 221 from article 2.2",
            "data": []
          },
          {
            "id": "a-222",
            "id_parent": "a-22",
            "value": "Quote 222 from article 2.2",
            "data": []
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

This output is needed for a treetable. The recursive function gives a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error when processing a large amount of data. Also the tree can have a large number of children (son, grandson, etc.).
I tried to write a for loop, using a stack array, but I didn't succeed. I am rather confused and my code could be confusing as well.

```
function functionWithIteration (rows) {
  var my_stack = [null]
  var final_val = []

  while( my_stack.length > 0 ) {
    var ret_val = []
    var first_time = true
    var id = my_stack.pop()
    var temp_val = []
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

      var row = rows[i]
      var signal = true
      if (id == row.id_parent) {
        signal = false
        var new_element = {
          id: row.id,
          id_parent: row.id_parent,
          value: row.value,
          data: []
        }

        for (let property in row) {
          if (property == 'id' || property == 'id_parent' || property == 'value') {
            continue
          }
          new_element[property] = row[property]
        }

        if (first_time){
          ret_val.push(new_element)
          first_time = false
        }
        else {
          ret_val[ret_val.length - 1].data.push(new_element)
        }
      }
      if ( signal) {
        temp_val.push(ret_val)
        my_stack.push(row.id)
      }
    }
    final_val.push(temp_val)
  }

  return final_val
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your attempt at the stack solution.

Comment: No amount of data should be large enough to get a stack overflow on a recursive tree traversal. It sounds more likely that your input tree is not a tree, but contains a circular structure.

Comment: @Bergi I added my attempt at the stack solution. My input does not gave the structure of a tree. It is one level json. The output has to be a multi-level json. My input data has 10000 rows and this gives me a stack overflow error.

Comment: I mean an input like `[{id: 1, parent_id: 2}, {id: 2, parent_id: 1}]`. That's a flat array encoding a circular graph, and would cause a stack overflow (or out-of-memory-error) on any code that assumes a tree.

Comment: @Bergi You were right. There was an error in my input (circular structure) and that caused the stack overflow error. Anyway, couldn't a very large tree traversal give a stack overflow while running a recursive function? I have in mind the classical example with factorial function (the iteration is preferred to recursive function).

Comment: Yes, a really large input could cause a stackoverflow as well - e.g. a list (degenerate tree) with millions of nodes. But iterative (with an explicit stack) isn't better here: you 'd still get an out-of-memory error on small devices. Instead, use an algorithm with a lookup map like in the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop approach with an object for known id and parents.

This solution does not expect data in sorted order.

```js
var data = [{ id: "c-1", id_parent: null, value: "Chapter 1" }, { id: "a-1", id_parent: "c-1", value: "Article 1.1" }, { id: "a-2", id_parent: "c-1", value: "Article 1.2" }, { id: "c-2", id_parent: null, value: "Chapter 2" }, { id: "a-21", id_parent: "c-2", value: "Article 2.1" }, { id: "a-22", id_parent: "c-2", value: "Article 2.2" }, { id: "a-221", id_parent: "a-22", value: "Quote 221 from article 2.2" }, { id: "a-222", id_parent: "a-22", value: "Quote 222 from article 2.2" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
                a.children = o[a.id].children;
            }
            o[a.id] = a;
            o[a.id_parent] = o[a.id_parent] || {};
            o[a.id_parent].children = o[a.id_parent].children || [];
            o[a.id_parent].children.push(a);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This was a helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather simple solution once you figure out the simple step of holding references to the objects. Loop over the array and create an object with the element id as the key. You than use that to reference the element to add its children.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "c-1",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-1",
    "id_parent": "c-1",
    "value": "Article 1.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-2",
    "id_parent": "c-1",
    "value": "Article 1.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "c-2",
    "id_parent": null,
    "value": "Chapter 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-21",
    "id_parent": "c-2",
    "value": "Article 2.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-22",
    "id_parent": "c-2",
    "value": "Article 2.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-221",
    "id_parent": "a-22",
    "value": "Quote 221 from article 2.2"
  },
  {
    "id": "a-222",
    "id_parent": "a-22",
    "value": "Quote 222 from article 2.2"
  }
]

// we use reduce to loop over the object to build up our new object.
var result = data.reduce((obj, itm) => {
  // store it into a obj so we can reference it
  obj.temp[itm.id] = itm
  // check to see if we have a parent
  if (itm.id_parent) {
    // if we have a parent see if data is set yet
    // if not, set it to an empty array
    obj.temp[itm.id_parent].data = obj.temp[itm.id_parent].data || []
    // push the child into the parent
    obj.temp[itm.id_parent].data.push(obj.temp[itm.id])
  } else {
    // If we have no parent, than it is a root element
    // or we push it into an array to keep track of it
    obj.order.push(obj.temp[itm.id])
  }
  // return the object for reduces next iteration
  return obj
}, { temp:{}, order:[]}) // init recude with an empty object and array
  .order  // return the order

console.log(result)
```

This solution is expecting that the parents appear before their children. If that is not the case, than there are a couple of things you can do. Either sort of you create a "temp" object until you find the real one.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's an error in your logic.  When it recurses, it appears to start over *from the beginning.*  Intuitively this would allow the recursive instance to stumble into exactly the same condition as before and thus to recurse *ad infinitum.* (In terms of the logic, multiple nested instances wind up with the same value for the loop-variable `i`.)

Comment: No, it doesn't start over, as the `id` parameter would have changed. Yes, the linear search for the children with the respective parent isn't terribly efficient, but it's not an infinite recursion (as long as the input actually encodes a bounded tree).